# How do I empty a list of icons in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a very simple quiz game that starts with an empty list of icons to record if answers are right or wrong.

```
List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [];
```

Correct answers append the list with a green check icon
Wrong answers append the list with a red X icon

Once all of the questions are answered I'm able to restart the list of questions again but can't solve how to empty scoreKeeper.

This is what I have tried.

```
if (quizBrain.isFinshed() == true) {
    print('time to empty the scorekeeper list');
    scoreKeeper.remove(0-scoreKeeper.length -1);
    }
```

Comment: ```scoreKeeper.clear()``` just clear all inside your list

Comment: @Reign that's what I was looking for.